# javascript elem.childNodes telling the future?

Tags: javascript, html

so, I am looping through elem.childNodes and modifying the child nodes. And, I get the following behavior. Why?

html:

```
<div>
   <p>
   </p>
</div>
```

what I expect to happen:

```
1. elem = div
2. console.log(elem.childNodes) = [p]    (this is what I expect console.log to output)
3. elem.html("<p></p><p></p>");
```

What actually happens:

```
1. elem = div
2. console.log(elem.childNodes) = [p, p] (yes, console.log outputs 2 p elements before I even run elem.html)
3. elem.html("<p></p><p></p>");
```

Note:

```
if I don't run elem.html("<p></p><p></p>"); after console.log(elem.childNodes), console.log(elem.childNodes) outputs [p]
```

Comment: see if it happens that way on other browsers

Comment: What happens if you call `setTimeout(function () { elem.html("<p></p><p></p>"); }, 0)`?

Answer (score 1):

[*childNodes*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1451460987) is a live [*NodeList*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-536297177). I suspect that *console.log* is showing the status of *elem.childNodes* when the function has finished, not at the instant it is called.

Note that *console* is a proprietary extension, so it's behviour may be different in different browsers if it's supported at all.

Comment: (+1) that's right. If the OP logged `elem.childNodes.length` instead, he would see `1`, not `2`.

Comment: thanks. For future reference, the chromium browser is the one whose console is showing the status of elem.childNodes when the function has finished, not at the instant it is called.